# String matching in Python

Tags: python, string-matching

does anyone know which string matching algorithm is implemented in Python?

Comment: What do you mean by string matching algorithm? Give an example of use please.

Comment: The answer is: “Both.” (“…country AND western…”)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Per [the sources](http://svn.python.org/view/python/trunk/Objects/stringlib/fastsearch.h?revision=77470&view=markup), it's a

> fast search/count implementation,
>   based on a mix between boyer-moore and
>   horspool, with a few more bells and
>   whistles on the top.  for some more
>   background, see:
>   http://effbot.org/zone/stringlib.htm

The [essay](http://effbot.org/zone/stringlib.htm) in question is really well worth reading!

Answer (score 1):

I assume you're talking about CPython.  In that case, you could always [check the source](http://svn.python.org/view/python/trunk/) (see [fastsearch.h](http://svn.python.org/view/python/trunk/Objects/stringlib/fastsearch.h?view=markup)).